# Execute external Get url request

Tags: php, curl, yii

So, I have this method where I need to call an external url (different domain). It's something like `http://192.168.2.2:9090/send?num=100&txt=text;` Is there any way to do this without using curl?

I guess I should clarify that I have tried using curl with the yii-curl extension but somehow it doesn;t seem to work. It works when I supply a whole formatted url, but if I try to modify the url with params for num and txt, it doesn't work for some reason. Preferably I am looking for a solution without curl, but if that is not possible I could use some help with how to format and execute a proper url so I can also supply params to the url. Thanks.

**Edit:** I don't think file_get_contents() will work as the url is actually to an SMS gateway that sends sms. the phone number and sms text is supplied as params. Let me know if I am guessing it wrong.

**Edit 2**: This is what I tried after the suggestions here.

```
public function sendTXTSMS($sentToNum,$text)
        {

            $construct_url="http://192.168.2.2:9090/send?num={$sentToNum}&txt={$text}";
            file_get_contents($construct_url);
        }
```

And then calling it like,

```
    $text='Lorem ipsum dolor ........ ';
$this->sendTXTSMS(XXXXXXXXXX,$text)
```

XXXXXXXXXX is of course the phone number masked here.

Now I am getting an  `HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request` error. allow_url_fopen  is enabled and I can access the url fine by typing it on a browser. Also tried using urlencode on the url.

Comment: pretty much all of the php file functions will work with a url if url_fopen is enabled in php.ini (which I believe it is by default. It usually is for all my installations). So file_get_contents($url) will return a string.

Comment: Won't work. The url is actually to an SMS gateway that sends sms. the phone number and sms text is supplied as params.

Comment: You could use ajax too.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean by "won't work"? Why will it not work? What did you try that didn't work? Did you get an error when trying it? Why does it being an SMS gateway prevent it from working? If the sms gateway is just a server waiting for requests just like any other server that accepts http requests (even if under a different port) it should work. How is the sms gateway different in that it accepts curl requests but not http requests from standard php?

Comment: @Jonathan Kuhn, well I guess I was confused with the function name file_get_contents having something to do with files only. The thing is still weird though,I am guessing I am passing the params to the url wrong. Like if this is the url http://192.168.2.2:9090/send?num=100&txt=text it is working with file_get_contents(), but when I try to modify the value of text supplying a variable, it gets messed up and I get a bad request error (I also tried urlencode). How should I be passing the variable say $text as the text here?

Comment: @redGREENblue PHP file functions will use the protocol passed in as part of the filename such as "http://" (if no protocol, it defaults to "file:///" which is for files) to determine how to open a file. This includes "ftp://", "php://", "ssl://" and more. For the problem you are having, just double check the url before you go out. `var_dump($construct_url);` and check if it matches what you think it should. As far as the code you showed, there is nothing wrong. As for urlencode, you should be using it, but just around the `$sentToNum` and `$text` vars, not the whole url.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a GET request you can use `file_get_contents($url);`.

If you need more options you can try the [HTTP library](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.http.php), but there's little reason to not directly use libcurl.  It's standard practice.

The fact it's connecting to a service related to SMS is irrelevant.  If it's a URL for a web service on a server you can connect to, you can make a request to it.

Answer (score 1):

`file_get_contents()` will work if `allow_url_fopen` is enabled in `php.ini`, but I think your problem is this:

> It works when I supply a whole formatted url, **but if I try to modify
>   the url with params for num and txt**, it doesn't work for some reason.

You need to encode the data:

```
$test = urlencode($text);
$sentToNum = urlencode($sentToNum);
$construct_url = "http://192.168.2.2:9090/send?num={$sentToNum}&txt={$text}";
```

Comment: @redGREENblue: Well that's it.  Try double quotes " instead.

Comment: Replace the brace or enclose the braces within quote, cause I tried both and its still not working.

Comment: Basic PHP.  vars in single quotes aren't evaluated.  You could see this if you just echo the var that holds that string you posted. $url = "192.168.2.2:9090/send?num={$num}&txt={$text}";

Comment: Wow, never knew that, Thanks. Unfortunately its still not working. I have also tried using urlencode on the url (please see my edit) thinking it may be malforming the url, but still keep getting bad request error.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use `file_get_contents` http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Answer (score 0):

Using curl should be a better option since you can easily deal with http status code...

But with or without curl, you need to build your url correctly, `urlencode` should be used on params, not on url :

```
$sentToNum = urlencode($sentToNum);
$text = urlencode($text);
$construct_url="http://192.168.2.2:9090/send?num={$sentToNum}&txt={$text}";
```